# I am learning express and mongoose and I cannot get a schema to save, but can see it with console.log()

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

EDIT: I think weekCount is saving before the records are loaded into it. Perhaps incorrect use of the find()?

I have started a website to record animals in camps (paddocks). I am using express, mongo, mongoose, and pug.

I have a schema (see below) that has an array of type: Schema.Types.ObjectId that I can not save to mongo. The array is empty.

I have a form that fetches the camp names, and the animal types (cows, bulls, calves) and creates a form.

The form is displayed, and the POST can read the form data. The form data is read into schema and is displayed ok with console.log, but does not save the entire schema in mongo.

I have read a lot of posts, and tried many things such as markModified, used a full Schema.

Its been hours now, and I would appreciate some help.

Express mongoose Models:

```
var WeekCountSchema = new Schema({
  dateOfCount: { type: Date },
  campCounts: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CampCount'}]  < ----- problem
});

var CampCountSchema = new Schema({
      campName: String,
      campCountDate: Date,
      count: {
        ox: Number,
        cow: Number,
        bull: Number,
        heifer: Number,
        calf: Number,
        weaner: Number
      }
});
```

```
weekCountController:
Scroll Down to the <---- 

exports.weekCount_create_post = [

  validator
    .body("dateOfCount", "Week Count Data Required")
    .toDate()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .trim(),


  validator.sanitizeBody("*").escape(),


  (req, res, next) => {
    var weekCount = new WeekCount({
      dateOfCount: req.body.dateOfCount
    });


    const errors = validator.validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      // There are errors. Render the form again with sanitized values/error messages.
      console.log("ERRORS!s");
      async.parallel(
        {
          camps: function(callback) {
            Camp.find()
              .sort("name")
              .exec(callback);
          },
          cattleClasses: function(callback) {
            CattleClass.find(callback);
          }
        },
        function(err, results) {
          if (err) {
            return next(err);
          }
          res.render("weekCount_form", {
            title: "There were Errors! New Week Count",
            camps: results.camps,
            cattleClasses: results.cattleClasses
          });
        }
      );

      return;
    } else {
      // Data from form is valid.


      Camp.find({}, "name").exec(function(err, list_camps) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }

        CattleClass.find({}, "name").exec(function(err, list_cattleClasses) {
          if (err) {
            return next(err);
          }

          var campCountArray = [];
          list_camps.forEach(function(campName) {
            var campCount = new CampCount({
              campName: campName.name
            });

            var emptyCount = true;
            list_cattleClasses.forEach(function(cattleClassName) {
              var tempVar = campName.name + "." + cattleClassName.name;
              var tempNum = parseInt(req.body[tempVar]);
              // console.log(tempNum);
              if (tempNum) {
                // console.log(req.body[tempVar]);
                campCount.count[cattleClassName.name] = req.body[tempVar];
                emptyCount = false;
              } else {
                campCount.count[cattleClassName.name] = 0;
              }
            });

            if (!emptyCount) {
              campCount.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                  return next(err);
                }
              });

              campCountArray.push(campCount);
            }
          });
          console.log("CampCountArray");
          console.log(campCountArray);
          weekCount.campCounts = campCountArray;
        });
      });

      // ****************************************************************
      // Check if Week Count with same date already exists.
      WeekCount.findOne({ dateOfCount: req.body.dateOfCount }).exec(function(
        err,
        found_weekCount
      ) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("ERROR findone " + err);
          return next(err);
        }
        if (found_weekCount) {
          // Week count exists, redirect to its detail page.
          console.log("FOUND");
          res.redirect(found_weekCount.url);
        } else {
          console.log("NOT FOUND");
          // weekCount.markModified('campCounts');
          weekCount.save(function(err) {            // <---- does not save 
            if (err) {
              console.log("ERROR SAVING: " + err);
              return next(err);
            }
            console.log("weekCount saved");
            console.log(weekCount);
            // output below

            // Week Count saved. Redirect to week count detail page.

            //   console.log(weekCount.campCounts);
            res.redirect(weekCount.url);

          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
];
```

Output from console.log:

```
GET /catalog/WeekCount/create 200 219.085 ms - 3782
NOT FOUND  <------ count not a duplicate (OK)
CampCountArray
[ { count: { calf: 1, bull: 0, cow: 0, weaner: 0, ox: 0, heifer: 0 },
    _id: 5d83720e2279011e90a1614b,
    campName: 'Bloekom' },
  { count: { calf: 1, bull: 0, cow: 0, weaner: 0, ox: 0, heifer: 0 },
    _id: 5d83720e2279011e90a1614c,
    campName: 'Davel' },
  { count: { calf: 1, bull: 0, cow: 0, weaner: 0, ox: 0, heifer: 0 },
    _id: 5d83720e2279011e90a1614d,
    campName: 'Elfas' },
  { count: { calf: 1, bull: 0, cow: 0, weaner: 0, ox: 0, heifer: 0 },
    _id: 5d83720e2279011e90a1614e,
    campName: 'Groot kamp' } ]
weekCount saved
{ campCounts: 
   [ { count: [Object],
       _id: 5d83720e2279011e90a1614b,
       campName: 'Bloekom',
       __v: 0 },
     { count: [Object],
       _id: 5d83720e2279011e90a1614c,
       campName: 'Davel',
       __v: 0 },
     { count: [Object],
       _id: 5d83720e2279011e90a1614d,
       campName: 'Elfas',
       __v: 0 },
     { count: [Object],
       _id: 5d83720e2279011e90a1614e,
       campName: 'Groot kamp',
       __v: 0 } ],
  _id: 5d83720e2279011e90a1614a,
  dateOfCount: 2019-09-06T00:00:00.000Z,
  __v: 0 }
```

from mongo:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d83720e2279011e90a1614a"),
        "campCounts" : [ ],  <---------------------- nothing here!
        "dateOfCount" : ISODate("2019-09-06T00:00:00Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
```

the campCounts ARE in mongo (sample):

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d83720e2279011e90a1614d"),
        "count" : {
                "calf" : 1,
                "bull" : 0,
                "cow" : 0,
                "weaner" : 0,
                "ox" : 0,
                "heifer" : 0
        },
        "campName" : "Elfas",
        "__v" : 0
}
```

but weekCount does not update. This is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your suspicion is correct that weekCount is saving before the CattleClass.find() callback has finished executing.

You could fix this with .then syntax:

```
CattleClass.find({}, "name").exec(function(err, list_cattleClasses) {

...     

}).then( function () {
  WeekCount.findOne({ dateOfCount: req.body.dateOfCount }).exec(function(
  err, found_weekCount) {

  ...

  }
})
```

you could also use ES6 async/await syntax, but your code would take quite a bit of rewriting because you can't use .exec() with await.

Both methods will ensure `CattleClass.find()` finishes executing before running `WeekCount.findOne()`

If you need more info there are lots of great posts on Stack Overflow addressing asynchronous code.

Comment: I have been able to save with dummy data, so this is the problem.  rewriting it now. Will post solution when done. Thanks for the help, it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works properly now.

Use of .then() instead of mixing callbacks and promises.
Thanks for the help!

```
exports.weekCount_create_post = [
  validator
    .body("dateOfCount", "Week Count Data Required")
    .toDate()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .trim(),

  // Sanitize (escape) the name field.
  validator.sanitizeBody("*").escape(),

  // Process request after validation and sanitization.
  (req, res, next) => {
    var weekCountDetail = {
      dateOfCount: req.body.dateOfCount
    };

    const errors = validator.validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      // There are errors. Render the form again with sanitized values/error messages.
      console.log("ERRORS!s");
      async.parallel(
        {
          camps: function(callback) {
            Camp.find()
              .sort("name")
              .exec(callback);
          },
          cattleClasses: function(callback) {
            CattleClass.find(callback);
          }
        },
        function(err, results) {
          if (err) {
            return next(err);
          }
          res.render("weekCount_form", {
            title: "There were Errors! New Week Count",
            camps: results.camps,
            cattleClasses: results.cattleClasses
          });
        }
      );

      return;
    } else {
      Camp.find({}, "name")
        .exec()
        .then(list_camps => {
          return CattleClass.find({}, "name")
            .exec()
            .then(list_cattleClasses => {
              return [list_camps, list_cattleClasses];
            });
        })
        .then(qResult => {
          list_camps = qResult[0];
          list_cattleClasses = qResult[1];
          var campCountArray = [];

          list_camps.forEach(function(campName) {
            var campCount = new CampCount({
              campName: campName.name
            });

            var emptyCount = true;
            list_cattleClasses.forEach(function(cattleClassName) {
              var tempVar = campName.name + "." + cattleClassName.name;
              var tempNum = parseInt(req.body[tempVar]);
              if (tempNum) {
                campCount.count[cattleClassName.name] = req.body[tempVar];
                emptyCount = false;
              } else {
                campCount.count[cattleClassName.name] = 0;
              }
            });

            if (!emptyCount) {
              campCount.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                  return next(err);
                }
              });

              campCountArray.push(campCount);
            }
          });

          weekCountDetail.campCounts = campCountArray;
          return weekCountDetail;
        })
        .then(weekCountDetail => {
          WeekCount.findOne({ dateOfCount: req.body.dateOfCount })
            .exec()
            .then(found_weekCount => {
              if (found_weekCount) {
                res.redirect(found_weekCount.url);
              } else {
                console.log("Not FOUND");
                var weekCount = new WeekCount(weekCountDetail);
                console.log("WEEKCOUNT3");
                console.log(weekCount);
                weekCount.save(err => {
                  if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                  }
                  res.redirect(weekCount.url);
                });
              }
            })

            .catch(err => {
              console.log("error findOne " + err);
              return next(err);
            });
        });
    }
  }
];
```